# JMeter GUI - execute using NewDriver failed to view Function Helper Dialog

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I try to test a new function in JMeter.

I download JMeter 3.3 code and add plugins including JMeterPluginsCMD

I also download jmeter-plugins-extras-1.4.0.jar with HttpSimpleTableControlGui class

I execute NewDriver which opens JMeter GUI, I try to open Options -> Function Helper Dialog but I have no functions

log:

```
2017-11-13 16:16:56,661 WARN o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Could not instantiate class: org.jmeterplugins.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpSimpleTableControlGui
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jmeterplugins.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpSimpleTableControlGui
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.initializeMenus(MenuFactory.java:499) [core/:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.<clinit>(MenuFactory.java:169) [core/:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.WorkBenchGui.createPopupMenu(WorkBenchGui.java:119) [core/:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:159) [core/:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.EditCommand.doAction(EditCommand.java:46) [core/:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) [core/:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$0(ActionRouter.java:70) [core/:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$$Lambda$43/1433208870.run(Unknown Source) [core/:?]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
2017-11-13 16:16:59,670 ERROR o.a.j.g.a.ActionRouter: Error processing org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.CreateFunctionDialog@45e37a7e
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.gui.FunctionHelper.initParameterPanel(FunctionHelper.java:165) ~[core/:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.gui.FunctionHelper.setVisible(FunctionHelper.java:228) ~[core/:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.CreateFunctionDialog.doAction(CreateFunctionDialog.java:50) ~[core/:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) [core/:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$0(ActionRouter.java:70) [core/:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$$Lambda$43/1433208870.run(Unknown Source) [core/:?]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The recommended way of installing JMeter Plugins and keeping them up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)
2. I do confirm that brand new JMeter 3.3 and [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) work fine together without any issues with [The Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper).

So my expectations are in:

- Your installation is broken, you should have:

  - `jmeter-plugins-table-server-2.2.jar` in "lib/ext" folder
  - `jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.4.jar` in "lib" folder
  - JMeter restart is required to pick any .jars up
- (most likely) Your function implementation is flaky. If this is the case you will need to provide your function code along with the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the right (or possible) way to call JMeter GUI is

```
 ant run_gui
```

Function Helper worked with my changes